# How is overload resolution performed in the case of an implicitly-deleted move constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, overload-resolution

As far as I know, when we have a set of overloaded functions, first the overload resolution is being performed, and only **after this** the access specifier is checked (such as `=delete`), and not the other way around. In other words, the code below

```
void f(int);
void f(double) = delete;

int main()
{
    f(42.2); // error, use of deleted function
}
```

[<kbd>Live on coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3426ee0566a93020)

produces an error, since `f(double)` is the best match and is deleted, and the compiler doesn't "fall back" on `f(int)`.

I also know that marking a destructor as `=delete` will implicitly delete the move constructor. So, I'd expect the following code

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(const Foo&) = default;
    ~Foo() = default; // implicitly deletes the move ctor
};

int main() 
{
    // Why doesn't the implicitly deleted move ctor 
    // participate in overload resolution?
    Foo mfoo = Foo{};
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/715396af805c36e0)

to fail, as the move constructor is `delete`d, but instead the compiler "falls through to copy constructor". Is this an exception in the C++ overload resolution process?

Comment: Declaring the destructor doesn't delete the move ctor; it makes it not-declared. http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy#9

Comment: @T.C. Thanks, this makes more sense then, although the terminology is terrible. I was thrown off by [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Deleted_implicitly-declared_move_constructor).

Comment: =delete is not an access-specifier, it's a function-body.